# Can $f(z)=\int_E \frac{dt}{t-z}$ be extended to an entire function?

Tags: analytic-continuation

Suppose that $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact and $m(E)>0$. Let $\Omega=\mathbb{C} \setminus E$ and 
\begin{equation}
f(z)=\int_E \frac{dt}{t-z}
\end{equation} for all $z \in \Omega$. I think that $f$ cannot be extended to an entire function because as $z \to \max E$ and $z>\max E$, we have $\frac{1}{t-z} \to -\infty$. Is my observation correct? Anyone can provide the details?

Comment: Hint: $f(z)\to0$ as $|z|\to\infty$. Now what kind of contradiction do you get if $f$ is assumed to be entire, in view of the Liouville's Theorem?

Comment: Maximum  and minimum may be isolated points of $E$. So your idea doesn't work.

Comment: I see the point now.  I really miss the use of  Liouville's Theorem.